# The iteration in my python code is not going till the max range

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my code. I am just replacing all the spaces in the string with "%20"

After the last iteration, when the value of i=18 and the len(var) is still 25, the code is exiting the for loop. Please help.

```
var1 = 'hello world ho are '
var=list(var1)
print(len(var1))
print(var1[5])

n =len(var)
for i in range(0, len(var)):
    print(i)
    print("length before", len(var))
    if(var[i] == " "):
        var[i+3:] = var[i+1:]
        var[i] = "%"
        var[i+1] = "2"
        var[i+2] = "0"
        print("length after",len(var))  
        print("value of i", i)

print(len(var))
print((var))
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a for loop, the sequence (`range(0, len(var))` in your example) is evaluated once, and an iterator for the sequence is returned. If you don't know what an iterator is - it means that `range(0, len(var))` is only calculated once - in the begining of the for loop execution, and so your loop iterates from 0 to 18 as in the orginal len(var) value, and the variable `i` is not effected by changes you make in the list.

If you were looping through the list itself (`for i in var:`) then `i` would have been effected by your changes, but it is best not to do so - you should copy a list if you are planning to change it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When the loop is entered, the length of the list `var` is calculated to be 18, and so the loop repeats 18 times.

The trouble is that you are changing the length of the list inside the loop. However this doesn't change the number 18 that was calculated at the start.

Instead of changing the list, build a new list inside the loop.

Or just use the replace method for python strings.

```
var1.replace(" ",%20")
```